# Eslint custom import order

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, eslint

Is it possible to make Eslint rule that supports custom import order

I want to trigger Eslint warning or error upon having following invalid order.

i.e

Invalid:

```
import utilsMicky from 'utils/micky';
import containersMicky from'containers/micky';
import componentsMicky from 'components/micky';
```

Valid:

```
import containersMicky from 'containers/micky';
import utilsMicky from 'utils/micky';
import componentsMicky from 'components/micky';
```

Comment: wait, why componentsMicky have to placed after utilsMicky? it doesn't ordered ascending or descending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently reading from the discussion [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495722/custom-eslint-import-rule-for-materialui) you probably would have to create your own ESLint rule for that kind of specific requirement. Their own requirement is to prevent people from importing from a nested path, as you can see in the [unit-test](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin-material-ui/src/rules/restricted-path-imports.test.js). Based on this, you could potentially implement a rule enforcing this specific import order of yours.

[eslint-plugin-import](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import) also has an existing [order related rule](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/order.md), but I haven't tested it so I'm not quite sure it fits for your requirement. Might be worth giving a try first :)

Hope this helps!