# Custom ESLint Import Rule for MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, import, material-ui, eslint

I have a project in React, using Material UI, and I am applying one of [their suggested methods](https://material-ui.com/guides/minimizing-bundle-size/#option-2) to reduce my bundle size.

Basically, I need to install the `babel-plugin-transform-imports` package and update the way we import components:

```
// Replace this (Option 1):
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
// Whith this (Option 2):
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
```

Everything is working fine, however, I would like to prevent the "wrong" imports (Option 1) in the future.

Is there a way to customize a ESLint rule that will force the Option 2 import **ONLY** when importing from the Material UI package?

I was reading about creating a custom ESLint rule, but would prefer to avoid that route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I found that Material UI created a package with their own custom ESLint rules:

**NPM Package:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-material-ui

**GitHub page:**

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-material-ui

They have a rule to solve my issue (`restricted-path-imports`), but that is not published yet. When they publish it, that may be the best way to go for me.

**Discussion about publishing the rule:**

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15610#issuecomment-512804075

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, custom is your only way to go. The only difference between these syntax is importing the default export or a named export. So if you want to prevent default imports specifically for the material-ui packages, you would need to create a custom eslint rule that looked at import statements AND match against material-ui as you don't want to error on all default imports.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have no experience in creating custom lin rules, so hopefully, someone else may have another idea to avoid this path.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2022**

*@kajirikajiri* actually made eslint plugin exactly for this!

https://github.com/kajirikajiri/eslint-plugin-mui-path-imports